# Connection error while sending email from host server

Tags: php

I have created a web application in php . I am using PHP Mailer 5.20 class. it work fine when I use XAMPP server on my local server but when we  host it on a web-server and try to send a email the it return an error i show you the error below

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
>   SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

I tried all configuration and check all but I receive the same error on the screen.

My PHP mailer class is below

```
<?php   require("PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");

function send_email($tomail,$message,$subject)
{
//$dbObj = new Database();
//$dbObj->connect_db();
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication

/////////////////////////////////( USER NAME AND PASSWORD )///////////////////////////// 
 $email = "xyxxxxx@yahoo.in";
$mail->Username = $email;  // SMTP username
$mail->Password ="xxxxxx"; // SMTP password


$mail->From = $email;
$mail->AddAddress($tomail, $tomail);

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
// set email format to HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody =$message;
$mail->Subject =  $subject;

$mail->FromName ="xyz (Online Booking Info)";

if(!$mail->Send())
{ $rr= $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;

}


 }

?>
```

Can some body tell me where am I wrong or miss configuration?

Comment: I don't know PHPMailer, but what you report sounds more like a network ing problem. Check if you can connect to that smtp server using telnet to the smtp port.

Comment: If that works you might proceed using a package sniffer like tcpdump or wireshark to control where that class actually wants to connect to.

Comment: Can you telnet the host ?  use this command "telnet smtp.mail.yahoo.com 25", it should return something along this lines: "Connected to smtp.mail.eu.am0.yahoodns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp127.mail.ird.yahoo.com ESMTP
"

Comment: Most probably, port 25 or 26 are blocked on your hosting server.

Comment: +1 @Dr.Dan - Most hosting providers block outgoing connections on TCP:25, and rightly so. In this case they will usually provide a smart host you can relay through, talk to your hosting provider.